# How to Get Server Time in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, client-object-model

How do you get the server DateTime in Silverlight in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

To get the current local time in Silverlight (as well as in regular .NET) you can use:

```
DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

To convert the DateTime to ISO 8601 DateTime format (for instance to use the DateTime value in a CAML query) you can use:

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

If you send a DateTime to the server in local time, the server will convert the time value into it's appropriate time zone. The best way to not have to deal with this at all is to use UTC time.

See [DateTime Time zone problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwcf/thread/b12f5e26-7699-46c8-b5b6-14ac2829be86/) for a discussion about this in relation to Silverlight.

Comment: I think you miss the word "server" in the op's question

Comment: The point is you shouldn't need to have to make a service call to get the server's time. The time zones are taken care of for you in time comparisons. Or if you always use UTC (which is a good practice anyhow) you still don't need to get the time from the server.

Comment: I agree with your point of view. But we should let the op describe it's requirement to see if it applies.

Comment: Touche. The answer does not directly answer his question, but it is the right way to do this. I see both sides to that argument.

Comment: since the silverlight is client application, the returned time is client loacal time, but each client loacal time may be difference, so in order to get consistent time, i need to get the server time.

Comment: In order to get a consistent time you use UTC. If you're worried about the client's clock being off on their computer, making a web service call could reduce this, but still is not completely accurate. If you introduce calls to web services to get the server time, when the response is received back from the server you've introduced your own inaccuracy in the form of a time offset (it takes a quantifiable amount of time to communicate back and forth with the server).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to make a service call, you will receive the datatime in the returned XML. [Take a look here for a starter on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh537940%28v=office.14%29.aspx)